# Date comparison using Predicate in NSFetchedResultsController with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My CoreData Entity has two attributes `date1` and `date2`. CoreData is backed up by an Sql based store. How can I fetch entities having same date1 and date2? (Ignoring the time. But while storing we cannot omit the time.)

I tried `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date1/86400 == date2/86400"]` , but it is not working.

Can I achieve this along with `NSFetchedResultsController`, or Do I need to do in-memory filtering using blocks/functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSFetchRequest` (or `NSFetchedResultsController`) with SQLite store, you are able only to do simple equality check or comparison (`date1` > `date2` etc.) in a predicate. You can use in-memory filtering, but you can also use a workaround to do the filtering while fetching.

Just add another two `NSDate` properties to your entity, let's call them: `day1` and `day2`. Then each time you save `date1` and `date2`, save a "stripped" date (without hours, minutes, seconds) to `day1` and `day2`. You can choose an arbitrary time in a day, like midday. Then simply use `@"day1 = day2"` in the predicate. This will improve performance and make working with `NSFetchedResultsController` easier, but also require more space for the storage.

As a side note, doing date calculations "by hand" like dividing by `86400` can fail [because one day does not always equal 24 hours](http://ronnqvi.st/working-with-dates/).

Comment: Ok thanks. I am planning to drop FRC and do in memory filtering for this date comparison.